# How to correctly formulate a sentence "m'a permis de ..."

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

I am describing the work that I did during my thesis as follows:

> Durant ma thèse j’ai travaillé sur un projet pluridisciplinaire entre
>   l’INSA et des paléographes de l’école des chartes. L’objectif était de
>   développer un logiciel pour classer automatiquement des milliers de
>   manuscrits médiévaux en utilisant des méthodes de classification
>   supervisée (SVM) et non-supervisée.  **Cette thèse m’a permis de gagner
>   de l’expérience à collaborer avec un public non expert dans
>   l’informatique. En effet il fallait leur fournir une interface
>   graphique facile à exploiter en gardant seulement les données
>   pertinentes et en cachant les détails inutiles.**

The problems are in the following two sentences:

- Cette thèse m’a permis de gagner de l’expérience à collaborer avec un public non expert dans l’informatique;
- En effet il fallait leur fournir une interface graphique facile à exploiter en gardant seulement les données pertinentes et en cachant les détails inutiles

---

In the first sentence the grammar is surely wrong. I really don't know how to link « m'a permis » with the rest of the words. In the second sentence shouldn't « leur fournir » be « leurs fournir » ?

Comment: Your whole text seems quite correct to me...

Comment: @LaurentS. i really can't grasp the grammar behind the first sentence. M'a premis de ... then à ... is that correct in french. Sorry For asking it.

Comment: I'm not a French professional like others here are that could provide a more formal answer. You could probably write "...m'a permis de gagner de l'expérience dans la collaboration avec..." Or "...m'a permis d'améliorer ma capacité à collaborer avec...", using a noun instead of one of the verbs. But still I think your original sentence is correct.

Comment: While I wouldn't be able to explain what sounds wrong with your first sentence, I think that Laurent's propositions sound more natural. Additionnally (this might be nitpicking), I would put a comma after "durant ma thèse" ([not 100 % mandatory](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.1.14) but sounds better) and after "en effet" ([apparently mandatory](https://scribium.com/annie-boroy/a/lecon-de-grammaire-pour-savoir-placer-les-virgules-sans-erreur/)).

Comment: Not related specially to the translation, but if I were you, I'd totally use the word "user experience", and "needs", because what you faced, was a small part of front-end (what the user needs, where, when, etc.), maybe not in a full well packaged and designed screen, but at least the beginning of UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence sounds odd but is technically correct, the second one is almost correct. Its neither *leur fournir* nor *leurs fournir* assuming you are talking about the *public*. This word is singular thus that must be *lui fournir*.

Here is what I would suggest:

> Me faisant collaborer avec un public non expert en informatique, cette thèse m’a permis d'enrichir mon expérience.

or

> Cette thèse m’a permis d'enrichir mon expérience en me conduisant à collaborer avec un public non expert en informatique.
>
> En effet, il a fallu lui fournir une interface graphique facile à exploiter, ne présentant que les données pertinentes et masquant les détails inutiles.

Comment: Ne pourrait-on pas considérer "leur fournir" comme désigant tacitement les membres dudit public ?

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est clairement au public (nom collectif)  que l'interface graphique a été fournie. L'accord d'un nom collectif peut se faire au pluriel quand il est accompagné d'un complément mais ce n'est pas le cas ici. S'il avait été écrit « un public de paléographes», « leur fournir » aurait été correct. En l'absence de complément à public, le pluriel me semble plus difficile à justifier.